# I2C returning Busy or Error on memory reading

Tags: stm32, ada, gnat

I started the following code to handle a [Bosch BME280 sensor](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/environmental-sensors/humidity-sensors-bme280/) with a Nucleo-F446ZE and a Nucleo-F411RE boards.

```vhdl
with STM32.Device; use STM32.Device;
with STM32.GPIO; use STM32.GPIO;
with STM32; use STM32;
with STM32.I2C;

with HAL.I2C; use HAL.I2C;
use HAL;

procedure Simple_I2C_Demo is

   --  I2C Bus selected
   Selected_I2C_Port      : constant access STM32.I2C.I2C_Port := I2C_1'Access;
   Selected_I2C_Port_AF   : constant GPIO_Alternate_Function := GPIO_AF_I2C1_4;
   Selected_I2C_Clock_Pin : GPIO_Point renames PB8;
   Selected_I2C_Data_Pin  : GPIO_Point renames PB9;

   Port : constant HAL.I2C.Any_I2C_Port := Selected_I2C_Port;

   --  Shift one because of 7-bit addressing
   I2C_Address : constant HAL.I2C.I2C_Address := 16#76# * 2;


   procedure SetupHardware is
      GPIO_Conf_AF : GPIO_Port_Configuration (Mode_AF);
      Selected_Clock_Speed : constant := 10_000;
   begin
      Enable_Clock (Selected_I2C_Clock_Pin);
      Enable_Clock (Selected_I2C_Data_Pin);

      Enable_Clock (Selected_I2C_Port.all);

      STM32.Device.Reset (Selected_I2C_Port.all);

      Configure_Alternate_Function (Selected_I2C_Clock_Pin, Selected_I2C_Port_AF);
      Configure_Alternate_Function (Selected_I2C_Data_Pin, Selected_I2C_Port_AF);

      GPIO_Conf_AF.AF_Speed       := Speed_100MHz;
      GPIO_Conf_AF.AF_Output_Type := Open_Drain;
      GPIO_Conf_AF.Resistors   := Pull_Up;
      Configure_IO (Selected_I2C_Clock_Pin, GPIO_Conf_AF);
      Configure_IO (Selected_I2C_Data_Pin, GPIO_Conf_AF);

      STM32.I2C.Configure
        (Selected_I2C_Port.all,
         (Clock_Speed          => Selected_Clock_Speed,
          Addressing_Mode      => STM32.I2C.Addressing_Mode_7bit,
          Own_Address          => 16#00#, others => <>));

      STM32.I2C.Set_State (Selected_I2C_Port.all, Enabled => True);
   end SetupHardware;

   ID : HAL.I2C.I2C_Data (1 .. 1);
   Status : HAL.I2C.I2C_Status;

begin

   SetupHardware;

   HAL.I2C.Mem_Read (This          => Port.all,
                 Addr          => I2C_Address,
                 Mem_Addr      => 16#D0#,
                 Mem_Addr_Size => HAL.I2C.Memory_Size_8b,
                 Data          => ID,
                 Status        => Status,
                 Timeout => 15000);

   if Status /= Ok then
      raise Program_Error with "I2C read error:" & Status'Img;
   end if;
end Simple_I2C_Demo;
```

In this simple example, I always get an error status at the end of reading. In the context of a more complete code, I always get a Busy status after waiting 15secs.

I really don't see what is going on as my code is largely inspired from [the code I found on Github](https://github.com/AdaCore/Lunar_Lander_Rotation_Demo) for a I2C sensor.

Maybe I forgot a specific code for I2C init but as I'm not an expert, I prefer to ask to experts :)

Comment: if you have a PC with linux you can use `i2c-tools` to test the Bosch sensor and its behavior and then implement this in ada code

Comment: In addition any sensor has its specific command codes to be accessed from I2C cf page 31 of the datasheet https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST-BME280_DS001-10.pdf

Comment: i would test this with `i2c-tools` following this guide: https://elinux.org/Interfacing_with_I2C_Devices

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any i2c interface on my PC so testing the behaviour is not possible using Linux tools. What I can say is that using MBed C++ example, the sensor works but as it relies on an old MBed framework, I can't inspect the whole code.

Comment: If you have a RaspberryPi you can install `i2c-tools` on it and use its I2C interface. You have to implement the commands (i.e. send the bus address of the Bosch) in the datasheet ( http://www.embeddedadventures.com/datasheets/BME280.pdf) on page 31 to only get access to the registers of the sensor, how you read the registers of the sensor is in paragraph **I2C read** on page 33. Is the address of the sensor you use in your code accurate anyway ? The default address is `76h` (hexadecimal) if SDO is connected to GND (datasheet page 32) *The problem is that i do not know ada*...

Comment: In https://github.com/AdaCore/Ada_Drivers_Library/blob/master/arch/ARM/STM32/drivers/i2c_stm32f7/stm32-i2c.adb is an ada driver, the function to read is `Master_Receive` (in I2C protocol there is only one master ) and you have to adapt the device and register addresses

Comment: Well using the STM32 package is not the way to do, it's better to use HAL instead, see https://github.com/AdaCore/Ada_Drivers_Library/blob/master/hal/src/hal-i2c.ads

Comment: Moreover, _Master_receive_ doesn't allow to read a specific register when _Mem_Read_ allows it

Comment: i made an answer because there is too much code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found what was wrong. After testing with C using STM HAL and investigating the Ada configuration code, I found that a line was missing:

```vhdl
      GPIO_Conf_AF.AF_Speed       := Speed_100MHz;
      GPIO_Conf_AF.AF_Output_Type := Open_Drain;
      GPIO_Conf_AF.Resistors   := Pull_Up;

      -- Missing configuration part of the record
      GPIO_Conf_AF.AF := Selected_I2C_Port_AF;
      -- That should be present even though there was a call to configure
      -- each pin few lines above

      Configure_IO (Selected_I2C_Clock_Pin, GPIO_Conf_AF);
      Configure_IO (Selected_I2C_Data_Pin, GPIO_Conf_AF);
```

Using *Configure_IO* after *Configure_Alternate_Function* crushes the configuration and, as there was a part of the record which was left uninitialized, the GPIO were incorrectly configured.

To be more precise, after looking at the code inside the GPIO handling, *Configure_IO* calls *Configure_Alternate_Function* using the *AF* part of the *GPIO_Port_Configuration* record. In my case, it was resetting it.

With the missing line, the code now runs correctly with *Mem_Read* and *Master_Transmit*/*Master_Receive*.

A big thanks to [ralf htp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5230735/ralf-htp) for advising me to dive into the generated C code.

Comment: The code [here](https://github.com/AdaCore/Ada_Drivers_Library/blob/master/boards/crazyflie/src/stm32-board.adb#L147) passes the `GPIO_Port_Configuration` as an aggregate, which means you can’t accidentally leave out a component (unless of course it has a default, but you’d still have to say `others => <>`)

Answer (score 1):

No, between `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read` and the `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit`, `wait`, `HAL_I2C_Master_Receive` procedure is only a nuance cf [How do I use the STM32CUBEF4 HAL library to read out the sensor data with i2c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230248/how-do-i-use-the-stm32cubef4-hal-library-to-read-out-the-sensor-data-with-i2c) . If you know what size of data you want to receive you can use the `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit`, wait, `HAL_I2C_Master_Receive` procedure.

A C++ HAL I2C example is in https://letanphuc.net/2017/05/stm32f0-i2c-tutorial-7/

```
//Trigger Temperature measurement 
buffer[0]=0x00;  
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1,0x40<<1,buffer,1,100);  
HAL_Delay(20);  
HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1,0x40<<1,buffer,2,100);  
//buffer[0] : MSB data 
//buffer[1] : LSB data 
rawT = buffer[0]<<8 | buffer[1]; //combine 2 8-bit into 1 16bit  
Temperature = ((float)rawT/65536)*165.0 -40.0;  
//Trigger Humidity measurement buffer[0]=0x01; 
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1,0x40<<1,buffer,1,100);  
HAL_Delay(20);  
HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1,0x40<<1,buffer,2,100);  
//buffer[0] : MSB data 
//buffer[1] : LSB data 
rawH = buffer[0]<<8 | buffer[1]; //combine 2 8-bit into 1 16bit  
Humidity = ((float)rawH/65536)*100.0; HAL_Delay(100); }
```

Note that it uses `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit`, waits 20 ms until the slave puts the data on the bus and then receives it with `HAL_I2C_Master_Receive`. This code is working, i tested it myself.

Possibly the problem is that the BME280 supports *single byte reads* and *multi-byte reads* (until it sends a NOACK and stop). `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read` waits for the ACK or stop but for some reasons it does not get it what causes the *Busy* and then *Timeout* behavior, cf page 33 of the datasheet http://www.embeddedadventures.com/datasheets/BME280.pdf for the multibyte read. You specified timeout to 15 sec and you get the timeout after 15 secs. *So it appears that the BME280 simply does not stop sending or it sends nothing including not a NOACK and Stop condition* ...

`HAL_I2C_Mem_Read` sometimes causes problems, this depends on the slave  https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/system/f/embedded-forum/7989/trouble-getting-values-with-i2c-using-hal_library

By the way with the

```
HAL.I2C.Mem_Read (This          => Port.all,
                 Addr          => I2C_Address,
                 Mem_Addr      => 16#D0#,
                 Mem_Addr_Size => HAL.I2C.Memory_Size_8b,
                 Data          => ID,
                 Status        => Status,
                 Timeout => 15000);
```

you try to read 1 byte the chip identification number from register `D0` cf http://www.embeddedadventures.com/datasheets/BME280.pdf page 26

Comment: There must be another problem in my configuration as even with your solution with _Master_Transmit_ and _Master_Receive_, it doesn't work.

Comment: I finally tested with C code generated from STM32Cube and _HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_ works like a charm. I need to investigate the Ada configuration part.